# how to override an assembly file in .net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtp

From the code below I need to replace

`SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost"` with `SmtpMail.SmtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"]`

```
 Public Shared Sub SendMailHTML(ToAdd As Object, FromAdd As Object, Message As Object,     Subject As Object)
  Dim msgMail As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
  msgMail.[To] = Conversions.ToString(ToAdd)
  msgMail.From = Conversions.ToString(FromAdd)
  msgMail.Subject = Conversions.ToString(Subject)
  msgMail.Headers.Add("X-Mailer", "ASP.NET")
  msgMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
  msgMail.Body = Conversions.ToString(Message)
  SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost"
  SmtpMail.Send(msgMail)
 End Sub
```

I don't have access to the assembly code just the compiled files. I've also tried decompiling and recompiling the assembly using different decompilers but get too many errors. Just wondering if we can create a new file and override it

Comment: If the class is not `sealed` you could subclass it and hide `SendMailHTML()` with your own implementation. (in C# with the `new` keyword)

Comment: The class is not sealed but the methods are not virtual. Also do I need to create a new vb.net class library project, reference this dll and then subclass it and override the method?

Comment: The `new` keyword allows you to 'hide' or 'override' non-virtual methods. You don't necessarily need a new class library project, just a new class that inherits from the class containing `SendMailHTML()`

Comment: The assembly name which has this file xxx.dll and the class name is Mail.vb which has this method. So I create a new Mail_Revised.vb file and inherit from the Mail.vb file. Use the new keyword and override this method.